# how to create a destroy-able on-boarding in flutter (it should be visible only on first installation and never again)?

Tags: flutter, dart

[on pressing the get started button it goes to next page but on clicking the back button it shows the onboarding again (don't want that to happen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlpMq.png)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Navigator.pushReplacement** method instead of using Navigator.push Method to move to the next page.

```
For ex :

Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()));
```

> Navigator.push method will add a new page/route in the navigation stack.
>
> While, Navigator.pushReplacement will replace the current page/route with the next page/route in the navigation stack in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shared_preferences` to keep record of show `OnboardingScreen`, in this emo `initScreen`
if `OnboardingScreen` never showed before then show `OnboardingScreen` else move to another screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

int initScreen;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
  initScreen = await prefs.getInt("initScreen");
  await prefs.setInt("initScreen", 1);
  print('initScreen ${initScreen}');
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: initScreen == 0 || initScreen == null ? "first" : "/",
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(
              title: "demo",
            ),
        "first": (context) => OnboardingScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

User Shared preferences to store data that user viewed onboarding screen or not. If viewed then don't load this screen again. And to go to another screen by replacing do code like below.

```
bottomSheet: _currentPage == _numPages - 1
      ? Container(
          height: 75.0,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "screen you want to go");
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Get started',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF5B16D0),
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      : Text(''),
```

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it helps you. @SomsubroBanerjee